# Modal backdrop with opacity causing google chrome to lag

Tags: performance, google-chrome, css

We have a simple modal in our web application.

It's nothing special and is built on twitters bootstrap library.
It contains a backdrop that is a semi transparent white background with `position: fixed` and `width` and `height` set to `100%`.

The modal itself, however, is not statically positioned but absolutely positioned, this is because the modal might be taller than the viewport and we don't want scrolling in the modal.

Here's the dilemma, when the backdrop is present the scrolling is far from smooth in Google Chrome, if I change the position of the backdrop to absolute everything is fine.
This has the obvious downside of not covering the entire page.

I tried to reproduce it with a JSFiddle but I couldn't (most likely due to the fact that we a lot more content on our site).
Nonetheless here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/LdC4w/

So, any ideas?

Oh, and I can add that having a background image instead of opacity is not an option.

Comment: Do you have any flash content on the page or in the modal itself? Which bootstrap version are you running by the way? I'll try to reproduce it locally.

Comment: Just tried reproducing it locally with bootstrap 2.2.1 with the same css you provided in the fiddle. Looped over big chunks of different content (text, flash, animated gifs, other images) 40 times and echoing out the result, but were unable to get the laggy scrolling you experienced. Do you have a live site we could have a look at?